# Second Firestore call in same function not querying

Tags: typescript, async-await, discord.js

I have this if statement in a function:

```
if(commander){
        if(outcome){            
            try { 
                await updateDoc(doc(db, 'commanders', commanderName), {
                    Wins:  commander.Wins + 1,
                    Games: commander.Games + 1,
                })
                return true;
            } catch(e){
                console.log(e);
            }
            try {
                await updateDoc(doc(db, 'players', playerName), {
                    Wins:  player.Wins +1,
                    Games: player.Games + 1,
                })
                return true;
            } catch(e){
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
```

Before this if statement I have confirmed that both `commanderName` and `playerName` exist and hold valid values.

Updating `commanders` works correctly here, but it seems like the code just skips over updating `players`.

It may also be mentioning that elsewhere in the app this function works correctly:

```
export async function addPlayer(playerName: string) {
    await setDoc(doc(db, 'players', playerName), {
        Name: playerName,
        Games: 0,
        Wins: 0,
    })
}
```

So I know that the naming and syntax of the `players` update is correct.

What could be the issue here? Is there an easy way for me to try to debug this that I don't know about? I am using VS code if that matters. If you need any additional information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the return statement, "return true" - this exits ....

Comment: Ya that's embarrassing thank you lol. I had reworked that function a couple times and I guess that just stuck around from last version and I didn't notice it.

Comment: It's easy to miss, especially when you've been starting at something!